Prove these $1$-forms are left-invariant on the complex Lie group

Consider the complex Lie subgroup
$$G=\left\{\left.\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x & y \\
0 & 1 & z \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \right\rvert\, x, y, z \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$$
in $G L(3, \mathbb{C})$. $G$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{3}$. Let $\Gamma$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of matrices where $x, y, z$ are Gauss integers (namely in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ). $\Gamma$ acts on $G$ by left multiplications, which are certainly biholomorphisms. The action is free and properly discontinuous. The quotient $M^{3}$ is a compact complex manifold, called the Iwasawa manifold.
Consider global holomorphic $1$-forms $\psi_{1}=d x$, $\psi_{2}=d y-x d z$, and $\psi_{3}=d z$ on $G$. It is easy to check that they are left-invariant, hence are invariant under the action of $\Gamma$, so they descend down to $M^3$. Note that $d \psi_{2}=-d x \wedge d z \neq 0$, so $M^{3}$ does not admit any Kähler metric.

Lets check $\psi_2$. For brevity, write $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x & y \\
0 & 1 & z \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ as $(x,y,z)$.

When the case is real, let $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, and
$$v=(v_1,v_2,v_3):=v_1\partial_x|_B+v_2\partial_y|_B+v_3\partial_z|_B\in T_BG,$$
We want to prove $\psi_2|_{L_A(B)}((L_A)_{*B}(v))=\psi_2|_B(v)$. Under $G\cong\mathbb R^3\cong T_BG$, let
$$\gamma(t)=vt+B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)t+(b_1,b_2,b_3),$$
then
\begin{align*}
(L_A)_{*B}(v)&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(L_A(\gamma(t)))=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(A(vt+B))\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(a_1+v_1t,a_2+a_1v_3t+v_2t,a_3+v_3t)\\
&=(v_1,v_2+a_1v_3,v_3).
\end{align*}
So we have
\begin{align*}
(dy-xdz)|_{L_A(B)}((L_A)_{*B}(v))&=(dy|_{AB}-(a_1+b_1)dz|_{AB})(v_1,v_2+a_1v_3,v_3)\\
&=v_2+a_1v_3-(a_1+b_1)v_3=v_2-b_1v_3\\
&=(dy|_B-b_1dz|_B)(v_1,v_2,v_3)\\
&=(dy-xdz)|_B(v).
\end{align*}

When the case is complex, by definition, two complex valued forms are equal iff they act equally on any complex tangent vector. So let $v\in T_B^\mathbb CG$ be
$$v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6):=v_1\partial_x|_B+v_2\partial_y|_B+v_3\partial_z|_B+v_4\partial_{\bar x}|_B+v_5\partial_{\bar y}|_B+v_6\partial_{\bar z}|_B,$$
where $v_i\in\mathbb C$. But $G$ has complex dimension $3$, and $T_B^\mathbb CG$ has complex dimension $6$, so $G\cong\mathbb C^3\ncong T_B^\mathbb CG$, which prevent us form writing $\gamma(t)$ as $vt+B$ like in the real case. So how do we compute $(L_A)_{*B}(v)$?
If you have any other methods, please feel free to answer, but it would be better if you could tell me how to calculate $(L_A)_{*B}(v)$ because I am very curious about the general differential geometric method to calculate $(L_A)_{*B}(v)$ when the case is complex. And $(L_A)_{*B}(v)$ is well-defined, so I think $(L_A)_{*B}(v)$ can definitely be expressed as $(?,?,?,?,?,?)$ in some way.

I don't think that the difference between real an complex is really relevant. The point is that the forms $dx$, $dy-xdz$ and $dz$ that you consider all are $(1,0)$-forms, so they and their pullbacks along holomorphic maps are all complex linear maps from tangent spaces to $\mathbb C$. Now a real basis for the real tangent space is a complex basis for the complex tangent spaces, so if two $(1,0)$-forms agree on all elements of this basis, they agree everywhere.
Howwever, I believe that you can sort out things much more easily by computing directly with differential forms. You can consider $x$, $y$, and $z$ as global holomorphic coordinates on $G$. Now if you take $A\in G$ with entries $x(A)=a$, $y(A)=b$ and $z(A)=c$, you immediately get how $L_A$ acts on these coordinates: $x\circ L_A=x+a$, $y\circ L_A=y+b+az$ and $z\circ L_A=z+c$. Applying the exterior derivative, you get $(L_A)^*dx=dx$, $(L_A)^*dy=dy+adz$ and $(L_A)^*dz=dz$. This already shows that $dx$ and $dz$ are left-invariant. Now $(L_A)^*xdz=(x\circ L_A)(L_A)^*dz=xdz+adz$ and this immediately implies that $dy-xdz$ is left-invariant.
